# How to LEFT JOIN more than 2 tables to get no records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the date of this week and the total sum of `total_price` even there is no transaction on the specific date. The problem is when I change the value of `tbl_barangay.city_id` into `2`, all the data of `tbl_barangay.city_id = 1` is included. I want to get all records according to the value of `tbl_barangay.city_id`. How can I left join more than 2 tables so I can get the expected data?

Sample data

```
    tbl_calendar                 tbl_city                   tbl_tran

date_id   date           city_id  city_name      tran_id  tran_date    city_id  
1         2019-08-19     1        Sala           1        2019-08-19   1
2         2019-08-20     2        Marinig        2        2019-08-20   1
3         2019-08-21     3        Pulo           3        2019-08-23   2
4         2019-08-22
5         2019-08-23
6         2019-08-24
7         2019-08-25
```

```
         tbl_tran_details

detail_id  item    total_price  tran_id
1          Item1   20           1
2          Item2   20           1
2          Item3   30           2
2          Item1   30           3
```

Expected data if the `tbl_city.city_id = 1`

```
Date         Total
2019-08-19   40  
2019-08-20   30
2019-08-21   0
2019-08-22   0
2019-08-23   0
2019-08-24   0
```

and if the `tbl_city.city_id = 2`

```
Date         Total
2019-08-19   0  
2019-08-20   0
2019-08-21   0
2019-08-22   0
2019-08-23   30
2019-08-24   0
```

```
  SELECT tbl_calendar.date Date, 
  SUM(IFNULL(tbl_tran_details.total_price,0)) Total FROM tbl_calendar
  LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_tran ON tbl_calendar.date = tbl_tran.tran_date
  LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_tran_details ON tbl_tran.tran_id = tbl_tran_details.tran_id
  LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_city ON tbl_tran.city_id = tbl_city.city_id AND tbl_city.city_id = 2
  WHERE 
  YEAR(tbl_calendar.date) = YEAR(NOW())
  AND
  WEEK(tbl_calendar.date) = WEEK(NOW())
  GROUP BY
  tbl_calendar.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you filter the cities in the wrong table because you want to get the sum of transactions for a certain city from the `tbl_tran` table, but you filter the cities in the `tbl_city` - which you do not even use in this query.

```
...
FROM (tbl_calendar
  LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_tran ON tbl_calendar.date = tbl_tran.tran_date AND tbl_tran.city_id = 2)
  LEFT JOIN 
  tbl_tran_details ON tbl_tran.tran_id = tbl_tran_details.tran_id
...
```